# Searching arrays for a value at specific indices... Pt. 2 Error Correction

Tags: java, android, arrays

So two days ago I asked for some help, and got some good stuff... [Searching arrays for a value at specific indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032016/searching-arrays-for-a-value-at-specific-indices)

Now I've tried to get as far as I could on my own, and I am stuck with an error of "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int" at `if(lLungArray[i]k] == 1)`

```
int[] lLungArray = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
int lLung;
private void checkHealth() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(MainActivity.panel1 == 0){
        if(MainActivity.panel2 == 0){
            int[] secondArray = {0,1,8,9};
            int lLungCount = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<lLungArray.length;i++){
                for(int k:secondArray){
                    if(lLungArray[i][k] == 1) //Error here {
                        lLungCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

My project is almost done, but I can't figure out how to resolve this error.  If you read my first question, you'll see I am a novice and google hasn't been much help.

Comment: I believe you come with this code by refering my answer from your previous question. you need 2 dimensional array for this.

Answer (score 0):

`lLungArray` is an array of `int` but here `lLungArray[i][k]` you're trying to provide 2 indexes which treats it as an array of arrays and that is plain wrong!

*Update:* Based on your comment,

> I'd like to know if lLungArray has a 1 in positions 0,1,8,9 and how many instances the 1 appears. Using the above lLungCount should end up at 4. Is that what if(lLungArray[i]==k){ will help me do?

I guess this will help you achieve what you want.

```
private void checkHealth() {
    int[] secondArray = { 0, 1, 8, 9 };
    int lLungCount = 0;
    for (int k : secondArray) {
            // If the lLungArray elements at the positions specified by the 
            // elements of secondArray is 1 then increment the lLungCount
        if (lLungArray[k] == 1) {
            lLungCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RJ I'd like to know if `lLungArray` has a 1 in positions `0,1,8,9` and how many instances the 1 appears.  Using the above `lLungCount` should end up at 4.  Is that what `if(lLungArray[i]==k){` will help me do?

Comment: It seems like `if(lLungArray[1]==k){` would search the `lLungArray` for a 0, 1, 8 or 9, instead of searching for a 1 at positions 0, 1, 8, and 9.  Again, I'm a novice so I'm just trying to put it into words and I'm probably wrong.

Comment: @user2329162 - No it wouldn't do that. Actually I just guessed that without knowing the actual requirement. I updated the answer to help you fix that problem. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

you declared an one dimensional array:

```
int[] lLungArray = {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
```

but you try to access it like a two dimensional array

```
if(lLungArray[i][k] == 1)
```

thats not possible

I think you want something like this:

```
secondArray[k] == 1
```

Comment: Ahhhh.  Okay, I thought that meant it would search `lLungArray` at the positions stated in the `secondArray`.

Answer (score 0):

`lLungArray[i][k]` means ith row and kth column (2-Dimensional array). But your array is one dimensional.